# Default Value in Excel Dropdown menu

Tags: excel

I have a dropdown list at the moment in B2 which as a blank box, Which is not clear to people using it that you have to select something from the Dropdown.

I want to display the word Select by default so they know they have to select.

I made a list which is cell AA1 to AA10

it's something like this
Select
Ireland
England
Scotland
France
Germany
Belgium
United States
Canada
Australia

I seen some examples of people using offset or IF classes. But I'm not sure if me storing the data in AA is confusing me.

I did try this 
    =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$AA:$AA)-1,1)

Also I don't want to use VBA as that will just add more complexity to it.

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just select "Select" from the dropdown and save the spreadsheet like that? That way, whenever the spreadsheet opens, "Select" appears in cell `B2` by default.

Comment: WIll that work ? .. i never thought of that. I've had a few other suggestions like adding select to the cell beside it and indenting it across on top of the dropdown.. which works as well.. but I was trying to find a formula way of doing it.

Comment: It should work. I don't think formulas will help with what you are trying to accomplish.